# Request header field Accept-Encoding is not allowed when using Google Drive and Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-drive-api

I have a piece of Angular JS which reads a json file located in my Google Drive:

```
yummy.controller("slideCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope) {
}]).directive('slideElement', ['$interval', '$http',($interval, $http) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var path = 'https://googledrive.com/host/0B-74lO-UfPKoaDRySEsyQkZwNjQ/';
        element.html('<div class="loading"><img src="img/loading.gif"></div>');
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: path + 'reduced.json'
        }).then(function(response) {
            console.log(response.data);
        });
}]);
```

In Chrome and Firefox as well as IE, the code runs without error. But in Safari, I get the following error:

```
Failed to load resource: Request header field Accept-Encoding is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
```

I have tried adding:

```
{ headers: { 'Accept-Encoding': undefined }}
```

But this doesn't solve my problem.

How can I make my code work in Safari? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue but it was because of a wrong setting on the server.

try the following code:

```
.directive('slideElement', function($http) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var path = 'https://googledrive.com/host/0B-74lO-UfPKoaDRySEsyQkZwNjQ/';
                element.html('<div>loading</div>');
                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: path + 'reduced.json',
                    headers : {
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
                    }
                }).then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response.data);
                }, function(err){console.log("err")});
            }
        }
    })
```

where header parameter with content-type is new.

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your response. But my code runs well in Chrome and FF. Only in Safari my code encounters problem. So I believe it is the Javascript problem, not the problem in server. Beside, I cannot change the setting in Google Drive.

Comment: depending on the server response then it could affect specific browser (some are more 'flexible' than others). Did you tried with Content-type paramenter?